# Will adhesive remover soak into concrete and eventually ruin the LVP that will be installed?

Tags: adhesive

We are removing carpet tile from a store front and need to install LVP. The carpet tile glue cannot be moved with a scraper, so I was planning on using adhesive remover on the existing glue. I was told that this adhesive remover would soak into the concrete and eventually eat away and ruin the LVP that is going to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to leave an awful heavy mess behind for that to happen. To be safe, though, I would maybe do a fresh water rinse after you're done and a wet-dry vac extraction. What's left, if allowed to dry, should be innocuous. Use fans and don't install your flooring until it's all dry.